# Recreating the functionality of the blue “unread dot” on the iPhone Mail app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am building an RSS reader with a GUI very similar to the built-in mail app. It uses Core Data to store the information once it is downloaded. When a story is downloaded, it has a blue dot to indicate it is new. Once I go back to the main page after reading a story the dot should be gone. It stays there until I scroll or relaunch the app. In the `viewWillAppear:` method, I call `[self.tableView reloadData];` which successfully calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for all visible cells. Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StoryCellIdentifier";
StoryCell *cell = (StoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StoryCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSUInteger thisRow = [indexPath row];
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [storyData objectAtIndex:thisRow];

cell.titleLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"title"] description];
cell.descLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"subTitle"] description];
if (!([managedObject valueForKey:@"new"]))
{
    cell.readIndicator.image = nil;
}

return cell;
}
```

The program hits the `cell.readIndicator.image = nil;` line when it should. In fact, the program follows the same execution path both when the dot is and is not there. Also, this is probably related, but when I click back on the Navigation Controller, the cell I had clicked on is still highlighted.

EDIT: The .m file that corresponds to the .xib is just boilerplate.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) 
    { }
    return self; 
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super setSelected:selected animated:animated]; 
 }
```

EDIT2:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    StoryView *storyView = [[StoryView alloc] initWithNibName:@"StoryView" bundle:nil];
    NewsItem *item = [storyData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [storyView viewLoaded:item];

// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
// ...
    item.new = NO;
    [managedObjectContext save:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:storyView animated:YES];

    [storyView release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is probably a separate bug is that your cell will show up wrong if a cell with an already-read item is re-used to display a not-read item...  you need to do something like

```
if (!([managedObject valueForKey:@"new"]))
{
    cell.readIndicator.image = nil;
}
else
{
    cell.readIndicator.image = blueDotImage;
}
```

rather than just assuming that the blue dot image was put there when the cell was created.

For the non-displaying part, I'm wondering if you need to call `setNeedsDisplay`--perhaps the cell isn't realizing it needs to be redrawn when you change the `readIndicator`'s image.

Comment: Where would I put setNeedsDisplay? Would it be [cell setNeedsDisplay]; just before the return?
My .xib has the blue dot there from the beginning. Should it just have a UIImageView that isn't preset as the blue dot?

Comment: I'm not sure if [cell setNeedsDisplay] or [cell.readIndicator setNeedsDisplay] or neither will help.

You can pre-fill the blue dot or not, you just need to handle the case where the dot isn't used for one cell but then is needed for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

For the cell remaining highlighted when popping VC, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882634/issue-with-deselectrowatindexpath-in-tableview/1882653#1882653)

For the main issue, perhaps you should post relevant parts of the custom table cell code for us to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `viewWillAppear` method firing? Try adding the `[table reloadData]` statement to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and see if that is working.

I had issues with the `viewWillAppear` method not always being called. Checkout [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing) for more info.

Comment: viewWillAppear is firing and when it fires it get the program to run through cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Could you paste the code of your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?