# How to change clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear when not using UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIViewController that manages a UISearchBar and UITableView. I've read that Apple discourage having multiple UIViewControllers manage part of your application, so I did not used UITableViewController to manage the UITableView. Instead, I implemented the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocol in my own UIViewController.

My question is, since I am no longer using UITableViewController, how do I actually change the `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` behavior? This property is part of UITableViewController.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Simply by calling

```
[myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

in your `viewWillAppear:` method.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. So essentially, I have to replicate the behavior manually myself. That's kinda rough, especially if there is something else that UITableViewController provides that is harder to accomplish.

Comment: I put this in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and it worked to deselect the row. `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)`

Answer (score 6):

Here the Swift code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely overriding the `viewWillAppear:animated` method and missing the `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` call.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an interactive animation:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if(selectedIndexPath) {
        if(self.transitionCoordinator != nil) {
            [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
                [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES];
            } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

            }];

            [self.transitionCoordinator notifyWhenInteractionChangesUsingBlock:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
                if(context.cancelled) {
                    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath
                                                animated:YES
                                          scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
                }
            }];
        } else {
            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:animated];
        }
    }
}
```

Swift Version:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        if let transitionCoordinator = self.transitionCoordinator {
            transitionCoordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
                self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true)
            }, completion: nil)

            transitionCoordinator.notifyWhenInteractionChanges { (context) in
                if context.isCancelled {
                    self.tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can scrub the animation, i.e. when interactively popping from a navigation controller. It also reselects the row if the interaction was cancelled. This is closer to what is happening inside `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 5:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to reload whole tableview.